# Why jQuery.easing error occurs while using jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, node.js, jquery-ui

I want to use add to cart effect in our project so I installed dependencies:(when I check package.json):

```
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
```

And I import these in the component which I want:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui'
```

But when I test it , It wont work:

**TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function**

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my problem was solved by declaring this snipped instead of jquery-ui:

```
import "jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-shake"
```

Best regards